# Symfony - Filter entities in custom EntityType Field by custom option

Tags: php, symfony

How to use a dynamic query on a custom field type ? What I mean by that:
I want to create a custom Entity Type form field which lists all the my `supplier` entities ... but, I want that custom form field to have an additional option `byStatus`. That option should then be used ( if set ) to set the `query_builder` option in order to retrieve only the suppliers where the status is equal to the `byStatus` option.

So here is my SupplierType:

```
class SupplierType extends AbstractType
{

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
            'byStatus' => 1,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                $q = $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
                    ->andWhere('s.status = :status')
                    ->setParameter('status', ????);

                return $q;
            }
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

So how can I replace the `????` by the `byStatus` option value.
And of course it should be possible to change the `byStatus` option when using the field type.

Like so:

```
$formMapper->add('supplier', SupplierType::class, [
    'byStatus' => -1,
]);
```

Comment: If you want to update the filter based on another field, shouldn't you instead filter using an AJAX-request in your template? Otherwise you would do a full reload of the page when changing the value, or am I missing something?

Comment: What I mean by that question is, do you maybe not want to (dynamically) filter inside the backend, i.e. the form type, but rather in your frontend using JS?

Comment: The title was misleading. I changed it and edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: So no, no need for filtering by JS in Frontend

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it. Actually very easy:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
        'byStatus' => 1,
    ));

    $resolver->setDefault('query_builder', function (Options $options) {
        return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
                ->andWhere('s.status = :status')
                ->setParameter('status', $options['byStatus']);
        };
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass in the option from another field I recommend using the `setNormalizers` as it allows you to pass in the options, i.e. other values, like this:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    // ... your setup without the query builder...

    $resolver->setNormalizers([
        'query_builder' => function (Options $options, $value) {
            return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
                    ->andWhere('s.status = :status')
                    ->setParameter('status', $options['byStatus'] ?? 1);
            };
        },
    ]);
}
```

See the docs for the OptionsResolver: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#option-normalization

edit: I added the `?? 1` which will only work with PHP7+, but it provides some safety when the option was not set. Search for null coalesce operator in the php docs if you don't know what it is.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But I get the following exception: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getQuery" of class "Closure".

Comment: Looks like an issue with the query builder. I just reused your example but without the (presumed) unnecessary variable `$q` or maybe option normalizers don't work properly with closures inside closures? I have to try this out myself, I can't see the error.

Comment: Thank you for trying. See my answer, I figured it out.