# How to render dynamic symfony form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have symfony 5.

class **FoodType** has list of sauce checkboxes

```
->add('sauces', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Sauce::class,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
 ])
```

**Sauce entity** has the desired method.

```
public function getAvailability(): bool
{
    return $this->availability;
}
```

**controller** create form and pass it to twig.

```
$form = $this->createForm(FoodType::class, $food);
```

**Twig** file

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

How can I implement something like this?

**pseudo code**

```
foreach($sauces as $sauce)
{
   if($sauce->getAvailability())
   {
     //show the sauce checkbox
   }
   else
   {
     //skip (hide) the checkbox
   }
}
```

That is, I would like to display only those sauce checkboxes that are available.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742959/symfony-filter-entities-in-custom-entitytype-field-by-custom-option/46744071?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony - Filter entities in custom EntityType Field by custom option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742959/symfony-filter-entities-in-custom-entitytype-field-by-custom-option)

Comment: Flagged it as a duplicate with above link provided by Nico. If it's not, please add into your question as to why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.

**class FoodType**

```
->add('sauces', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Sauce::class,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,

                'query_builder' => function (SauceRepository $sauceRepository) {
                    return $sauceRepository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->andWhere('s.availability = 1');
                }

            ])
```

Comment: @OP, note that query_builder was added. That's the main difference between your code in FoodType and the code in the answer.